# Creating a new command for commutative squares

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to define a command having as inputs  the vertices and arrows of a commutative square. But I'm having problems. Here's the code:

```
\newcommand{\csq}[8]{
\begin{tikzcd}
#1 \arrow{r}{#5} \arrow{d}{#8} & #2 \arrow{d}{#6} \\
#4 \arrow{r}{#7} & #3
\end{tikzcd}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ampersand replacement`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\csq}[8]{
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
#1 \arrow[r,#5] \arrow[d,#8] \& #2 \arrow[d,#6] \\
#4 \arrow[r,#7] \& #3
\end{tikzcd}
}


\begin{document}

\csq{A}{B}{C}{D}{"\phi"}{"f"}{"\psi",swap}{"g",swap}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed your syntax for the modern one using an argument for arrow options.

Comment: thanks! what was the problem with the ampersand?   Why did you use \& instead?

Comment: @Abellan PGF/TikZ (and tikz-cd inherits this) makes & an active character inside a YikZ matrix and this causes problems. Using `ampersand replacement`, & will not be made active and the macro provided will be  equal to `\pgfmatrixnextcell`. I used `\&` for commodity, but one can use any other valid macro name (`\aaaaaa`, for example, will work but it's too cumbersome).

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer has been given by Gonzalo Medina: use `ampersand replacement=\&` or directly `\pgfmatrixnextcell`. I would like to present a different realization, with a key value interface rather than eight arguments, that are difficult to remember.

The keys for specifying the corners are `tl` for “top left”, `tr` for “top right”, `bl` for “bottom left” and `br` for “bottom right”; for the arrows there are `t`, `b`, `l` and `r` for top, bottom, left and right. Note that the order in which the keys are specified is immaterial; if you don't want to label an arrow, just don't specify the relevant key.

You can also say `\ksq[<tikz options>]{<keys>}` in order to specify options for the `tikzcd` environment such as `row sep` or similar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz-cd}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ksq}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { abelian/ksq } { #2 }
  \__abelian_make_ksq:n { #1 }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { abelian/ksq }
 {
  tl .tl_set:N = \l__abelian_tl_tl,
  tr .tl_set:N = \l__abelian_tr_tl,
  bl .tl_set:N = \l__abelian_bl_tl,
  br .tl_set:N = \l__abelian_br_tl,
  t  .tl_set:N = \l__abelian_t_tl,
  l  .tl_set:N = \l__abelian_l_tl,
  r  .tl_set:N = \l__abelian_r_tl,
  b  .tl_set:N = \l__abelian_b_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__abelian_make_ksq:n #1
 {
  \begin{tikzcd}[#1]
    \l__abelian_tl_tl
    \arrow[r,"\l__abelian_t_tl"]
    \arrow[d,"\l__abelian_l_tl",swap]
    \pgfmatrixnextcell
    \l__abelian_tr_tl
    \arrow[d,"\l__abelian_r_tl"]
    \\
    \l__abelian_bl_tl
    \arrow[r,"\l__abelian_b_tl"]
    \pgfmatrixnextcell
    \l__abelian_br_tl
  \end{tikzcd}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\ksq{
  tl=A,
  tr=B,
  bl=C,
  br=D,
  t=\phi,
  b=\psi,
  l=f,
  r=g
}
\qquad
\ksq[row sep=3em,column sep=3em]{
  tl=A,
  tr=B,
  bl=C,
  br=D,
  t=\phi,
  b=\psi,
  l=f,
  r=g
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]